# Remotely control Mac cursor from iOS App (move mouse cursor programmatically)

Tags: ios, macos, cursor, mouse

Does anybody know how to do that? I've looked into the Mac Developer documentation but couldn't find a way to move mouse cursor programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should make a client on ios side, and next server on computer side and next control mouse using this server by establishing some protocol communicating through sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any VNC application to control a mac if you share the screen.

There is a free one (VNC Viewer) available as an extension in Chrome.  You can install it from within Chrome through the Play Store.  And there are some cheap pay ones in the Apple store.  This gives you complete control over the machine when you are on the same WiFi network.

You have to set the machine to be controlled up for screen sharing in the System Preferences > Sharing pane and log onto it remotely from the phone.

There are also a number of remote mouse apps in the Apple store, last I looked some have free trials, but none are completely free.